# Excel: Array Arguments Effect on AVERAGE function

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Typically, AVERAGE() includes non-numerical literals in its calculation. However, I am not sure why passing the values in as an argument causes AVERAGE() to simply ignore the FALSE values. Is there something special about passing arguments into AVERAGE() as an array? I know that AVERAGE() ignores non-numerical values passed in via cell references, but I am not sure about arrays, especially since the FALSE values are technically literals.

Comment: By literals, I mean values inputted directly into formulas as opposed to as cell references. For example, =func(1) v.s. =func(C1) where cell C1 contains the value 1.

Comment: In the language of Excel, your question pertains to how "strings" are treated by AVERAGE in 3 use-cases. **1.** Strings as arguments. **2.** Strings in arrays. **3.** Strings in ranges.  Arrays and ranges could be 1×1 or larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### String as Argument

In the AVERAGE function, Excel will attempt to coerce to a number any string entered as an argument.

For this reason, if you enter `FALSE` as an argument, Excel will coerce it to a zero.

For example,

- `FALSE` to `0`
- `TRUE` to `1`;
- `"1"` to `1`;
- `"6/4/2023"` to `45081`

### String in Array or Range

AVERAGE will NOT attempt to coerce strings to numbers if they are part of an array or range.

```
# In Argument 
=AVERAGE(FALSE,10)
=5

# In Range
=AVERAGE(A1,10)  // A1=FALSE 
=10

# In Array
=AVERAGE({FALSE,10})
=10
```

If you "do" want an attempt made to coerce strings in arrays and ranges to numbers, you can trigger that yourself by, for example, multiplying the array, or range, by one

```
# In Range
=AVERAGE(A1:A2*1)  // A1=FALSE,
=5                 // A2=10

# In Array
=AVERAGE({FALSE,10}*1)
=5
```

The automatic coercion of arguments that contain strings is likely a case of  Excel trying to be "helpful" since any other interpretation of the argument would assume the argument was explicitly added without any actual purpose.

There are other examples of functions where Excel will attempt to coerce arguments containing strings to numbers.  Typically, they are arguments where a string would also make little sense as an argument. For example, `=SUM("4")=4`

This can work in reverse where an argument should be one of two strings `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but will still  accept the numbers `1` or `0` as equivalent.

Comment: Would the same also apply to numbers written as strings and included in arrays? (I know about ranges) For example =AVERAGE({"1", 10})=10.

Comment: In response to your comment, I modified [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1787357/) to generalize more on "all" strings rather than specifically on `FALSE`. Hopefully that is more clear.

Comment: That is clear, thank you!